# How to Convert List<String> to List<Object> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of string that I want to convert into list of object.

```
List<Warehouse> getWarehouseSuggestions(String query) {
    final warehouseList = warehouses.entries.toList();
    final locIds = warehouseList.map((e) => e.value.name);
    List<String> a = List.of(locIds).where((warehouse) {
      final warehouseLower = warehouse.toLowerCase();
      final queryLower = query.toLowerCase();

      return warehouseLower.contains(queryLower);
    }).toList();

    List<Warehouse> b = List<Warehouse>.filled(a.length, a);
    return b;
  }
```

Comment: `List<Warehouse> b = a.map((string) => Warehouse(somethingRelatedToString)).toList();`

Comment: Wow! this solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know that, I've added a general answer to this for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map` on your `List<String>`, something like this:

```dart
List<Foo> foos = listOfString.map((s) => Foo(s)).toList();
// or
List<Foo> foos = listOfString.map(Foo).toList();
```

Comment: I think is `FooObject` instead of  `Foo`?

Comment: @JohnJoe Thanks for pointing it out. It's fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

conversion from JSON(Map<String, dynamic>) to Map<DateTime, List<*Object*>>

date_StatDataMap: (map['date_StatDataMap'] as Map<String, dynamic>).map((key, value) => MapEntry(DateTime.parse(key), value.map((StatsData) {return StatsDataModel.fromMap(StatsData);}).toList())).cast<DateTime, List>(),

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).